# How to auto fetch using join instead of creating additional queries with hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes, let's say Invoice and InvoiceItem:

```
public class Invoice {
   @Id
   private Integer invoiceId;
}

public class InvoiceItem {
   @Id
   private Integer invoiceItemId;

   @ManyToOne
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   private Invoice invoice;
}
```

If i load an instance of InvoiceItem using `EntityManager.get(id)` (or `Session.get(id)`) it gets the Invoice from the item using SQL join, so it creates only one query, doesn't matter how many results it fetches. But if i create a query:

```
select i from InvoiceItem i
```

It creates one query to fetch the InvoiceItem, and for every InvoiceItem it creates another additional query to fetch it's invoice.
I know i can change my query to something like:

```
select i from InvoiceItem i JOIN FETCH i.invoice as v
```

But i don't want to do this for every query i create, i want that hibernate fetch the children in the same query it creates to fetch the parent.

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: Maybe you need to writte the annotation @OneToMany in the class Invoice, because the annotation @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) must generate only one query, if you use @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) then it generates two queries. By the way, take care, when you use @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN), it loads all relations of the table, then the performance decreases, depends on amount of data. I hope this help you. Good luck.